# Is using std::filesystem with linux bad or the file system tree unreachable?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, filesystems, c++17

I'm trying to print the tree of the directories of my system but on using the root or somewhere near to it, the program throws an exception, like the following

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: status: Too many levels of symbolic links [/home/asmmo/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0]
```

And on using the root itself, the program throws

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: status: Too many levels of symbolic links [/sys/kernel/software_nodes/node2/dw-apb-uart.2/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1/firmware_node/physical_node1]
```

The code I used is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<filesystem>
#include<fstream>


void processPth(const std::filesystem::path&, std::ostream& = std::cout, const size_t& =0);

int main() {

    std::filesystem::path p{LR"(/home/asmmo)"};//or p{LR"(/)"} for the root
    std::ofstream myFile{"tree.txt"};
    processPth(p, myFile);

}




void processPth(const std::filesystem::path & p, std::ostream& ostream , const size_t& level ){
    if(!std::filesystem::exists(p)) return;//base case

    if(std::filesystem::is_regular_file(p))
        ostream<<std::string(2*level, ' ')<<"File: "<< p.filename()<<"\tSize: "<<std::filesystem::directory_entry(p).file_size()<<"\n";
    else if(std::filesystem::is_directory(p))
    {
        ostream<<std::string(2*level, ' ')<<"Directory: "<< p.filename()<<"\n";
        for(const auto& it : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(p))
            processPth( it, ostream, level+1);
    }


}
```

I tried to reach those `v0` using the terminal and the result as follows

```
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0$ cd v0
asmmo@asmmo:~/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0
```

When I try to print a tree for some near directory (like in the following code), it works fine.

```
int main() {

    std::filesystem::path p {std::filesystem::current_path()};
    std::ofstream myFile{"tree.txt"};
    processPth(p, myFile);

}
```

Comment: Do you understand what a *symbolic link* is?

Comment: @walnut no I don't. Is it related to a database  or something like that

Comment: Then I suggest that you read up on that first. You can then exclude symlinks from your loop using [`std::filesystem::is_symlink`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_symlink). They are links in the filesystem. E.g. in your first example `v0` is not a directory, it is a symlink that links to a directory above it, so it is recursive.

Comment: @walnut I understood now. thank U so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filesystem has a symlink that links back to one of its parent directories, then searching through that directory recursively will end in an infinite recursion, because the symlink will keep bringing you back to the parent directory.

The system allows only so many recursions and returns an error if you recurse too deep.

You should probably ignore symlinks when recursively iterating through a directory like that. You can use [`std::filesystem::is_symlink`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_symlink) to test whether a path is a symlink.